# Print multiple array values

Tags: php, echo

> I have the below code

```
    $student_IT_vitipare = mysql_query("SELECT * from notat where dega='teknologji informacioni' AND viti_lendes='viti pare' ");
  $vekt_stud_IT_vitipare = array();
  while ($kolo1 = mysql_fetch_array($student_IT_vitipare)) {
  $vekt_stud_IT_vitipare[] = $kolo1;
  }  
  $gjatesia_vektorit = count($vekt_stud_IT_vitipare);
```

> EXAMPLE: Array take from database name,last name and it has {john,trevis}{george,trolus} {dionis,karrblus} etc...
>   I know that if i want to echo out only name the code is :

```
for($i=0;i<$gjatesia_vektorit;i++){
   echo $vekt_stud_IT_vitipare[$i]['name'];
 }
```

> i've tryed $vekt_stud_IT_vitipare[$i]['name']['last name']; but it does not work

Comment: first: stop using `mysql_*` functions. They are dead. use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: Can you show us your array structure that you are getting in `$vekt_stud_IT_vitipare`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you should stop using mysql_* because it's removed on php 7.0 instead use mysqli_* or PDO**

your code won't work but instead if you do something like

```
for($i=0;i<$gjatesia_vektorit;i++){
echo $vekt_stud_IT_vitipare[$i][$i];
 }
```

it would but you will only one value

instead you need a nested foreach loop

```
foreach($vekt_stud_IT_vitipare as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $val) {              
       echo $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know that way but the problem is that i want to echo out only name and last name of array...but it has name,last name,departament etc

Comment: modify your query 
SELECT * from notat  * stands for all
instead SELECT name,last_name from notat

Comment: Ok it works but i want to compare name and last name with my database for example if dbname == val['name'] && dblastname == val['last name'] how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Share the exact sample array which you want to compare. I will try  to solve the problem. The one you shared is not sufficient.

The below array sample i need:

```
$vekt_stud_IT_vitipare
```